# How to get the buttons to work correctly

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the buttons to keep track of how many tickets are being sold and stop the loop when it hits a certain number. So far my buttons don't work at all (they show up but nothing happens when you click them) and I don't know why (first time trying to use buttons so I am probably forgetting something basic). Is there a simplier way of doing this?

```
        <div>Be aware that the maxium amount of ticket that can be purchased in one transaction is 10!</div>
    <div>Please press the button with the type of ticket you wish to purchase  to start ordering your tickets now.</div>
    <button onclick="Calculate(0);">Toddler Ticket</button>
    <button onclick="Calculate(1);">Junior Ticket</button>
    <button onclick="Calculate(2);">Adult Ticket</button>
    <div id='msg'></div>

</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Program name: Ticket Booth
        // Purpose: To do a transaction
        // Author: Ephraim Vickers
        // Date last modified: Today

        // Variables
            var MAX_SEAT_COUNT = 10             //Named constant
            var amountTicket                    //Amount of tickets bought
            var grossProfit
                    //Ticket prices
            var adulTicket = 0           
            var junTicket = 0
            var todTicket = 0
            var totalSales = 0                  // adulTicket + junTicket 
                    //Seats by class
            var adulNum = 0                     // number of tickets bought
            var junNum = 0
            var todNum = 0
            var extraNum = 0                    //Ticket bought over maximum

        function parseFloat(amountTicket) {

            if (amountTicket >= MAX_SEAT_COUNT) {
                extraNum = amountTicket - MAX_SEAT_COUNT;
                document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Tickets have now sold out thank you for purchasing."  // important to stop after limit
                 //end loop and display all data here like shown below remember to line up columns
                 //Ticket sale Report  <current date>
  // SEAT CAPACITY   EXTRAS            TOTAL SOLD
  // MAX_SEAT_COUNT  extraNum          amountTicket

  //  TODDLERS    JUNIORS               ADULTS
  //  todNum      junNum                  adulNum 
  //Gross Profit for today was grossProfit

              }else if    (amountTicket > 10) {
                 document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "The maximum number of tickets that can be done in one transaction is 10"
              }else {
                   amountTicket = prompt("Valued customer, please enter the number of tickets you would like to purchase.");
            parseFloat(amountTicket);
              }
              return;
              }
    function Calculate() {
        //set zeroes for all values
        adulTicket = 0
        junTicket = 0
        todTicket = 0
        amountTicket = 0
        totalSales = 0
        adulNum = 0
        junNum = 0
        todNum = 0
        extraNum = 0
        grossProfit = 0
       //get user input
        switch(id){
        case 0:
        todNum
        break;
        case 1:
       junNum
        break;
        case 2:
       adulnum
        break;
        }
       //get user input
            amountTicket = prompt("Valued customer, please enter the number of tickets you would like to purchase.");
            parseFloat(amountTicket);
        grossProfit =  (adulTicket * adultNum) + (junTicket * junNum)

            amountTicket = prompt("Valued customer, please enter the number of tickets you would like to purchase.");
            parseFloat(amountTicket);
        grossProfit =  (adulTicket * adultNum) + (junTicket * junNum)

    }

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think the best idea now would be to completely rewrite this part of your code, why?

- Every piece of visible html must be placed inside the body tag.
- Start with testing your code for only one specific class, multiple classes might work confusing and you can add those eventually when your code works for one class.
- Build your code (dynamic) so it will work for all your classes, this will make your life far more easier.

So what are you doing wrong in this code?

- You're passing a parameter in this calculate function, where are no parameters defined. Same as for your switch function, when is `id` defined?
- We don't see you logging. You're saying that nothing happens when clicking one of the buttons, but did you tried some logging already? There are probably some vars which are changing. Try to use `console.log()` to learn/see/explore/inspect.. your code.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

The code below works but I don't have the time to format it.

1 When you call a function with a button, you don't need a semicolon.

2 If your function has a parameter when you call it, like Calculate(0), you need to declare your parameter in the function.

```
function Calculate(ticket){

}
```

3 Then, that parameter must be used in the switch.

```
switch(ticket){

}
```

Other than that, variables should be declared outside of functions if you need them to work elsewhere.

Watch your if statements, this one had two outcomes for the same condition, and crashed my browser.

Please use this as a guide and tidy up your code. Formatting helps debugging.

```
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Program name: Ticket Booth
        // Purpose: To do a transaction
        // Author: Ephraim Vickers
        // Date last modified: Today

        // Variables
            var MAX_SEAT_COUNT = 10             //Named constant
            var amountTicket = 0                   //Amount of tickets bought
            var grossProfit
                    //Ticket prices
            var adulTicket = 0           
            var junTicket = 0
            var todTicket = 0
            var totalSales = 0                  // adulTicket + junTicket 
                    //Seats by class
            var adulNum = 0                     // number of tickets bought
            var junNum = 0
            var todNum = 0
            var extraNum = 0                    //Ticket bought over maximum

        function parseFloat(amountTicket) {

            if (amountTicket >= MAX_SEAT_COUNT) {
                extraNum = amountTicket - MAX_SEAT_COUNT;
                document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Tickets have now sold out thank you for purchasing."  // important to stop after limit
                 //end loop and display all data here like shown below remember to line up columns
                 //Ticket sale Report  <current date>
  // SEAT CAPACITY   EXTRAS            TOTAL SOLD
  // MAX_SEAT_COUNT  extraNum          amountTicket

  //  TODDLERS    JUNIORS               ADULTS
  //  todNum      junNum                  adulNum 
  //Gross Profit for today was grossProfit

              }else if    (amountTicket < 10) {
                 document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "The maximum number of tickets that can be done in one transaction is 10"
              }else {
                   amountTicket = prompt("Valued customer, please enter the number of tickets you would like to purchase.");
            parseFloat(amountTicket);
              }
              return;
              }
    function Calculate(ticket) {
        //set zeroes for all values
        adulTicket = 0
        junTicket = 0
        todTicket = 0
        amountTicket = 0
        totalSales = 0
        adulNum = 0
        junNum = 0
        todNum = 0
        extraNum = 0
        grossProfit = 0
       //get user input
        switch(ticket){
        case 0:
        todNum
        break;
        case 1:
       junNum
        break;
        case 2:
       adulnum
        break;
        }
       //get user input
            amountTicket = prompt("Valued customer, please enter the number of tickets you would like to purchase.");
            parseFloat(amountTicket);
        grossProfit =  (adulTicket * adultNum) + (junTicket * junNum)

    return amountTicket;
    }

    </script>
```